# What's the difference between var and let?

Tags: javascript, var, let

The [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables) for JavaScript says

> Back when JavaScript was first
>   created, there was only `var`. This works basically fine in most cases,
>   but it has some issues in the way it works — its design can sometimes
>   be confusing or downright annoying. So, let was created in modern
>   versions of JavaScript, a new keyword for creating variables that
>   works somewhat differently to `var`, fixing its issues in the process.

It continues to say

> For these reasons and more, we recommend that you use `let` as much as
>   possible in your code, rather than var. There is no reason to use `var`,
>   unless you need to support old versions of Internet Explorer with your
>   code (it doesn't support `let` until version 11; the modern Windows Edge
>   browser supports let just fine).

I'm looking at JavaScript code in [templates](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015) and [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_introduction_to_svg.htm) and, almost universally, I see `var` for initializing variables.

Are the differences over-stated between `var` and `let`?

Comment: No, the differences are absolutely not over-stated. `let` is somewhat new, so any tutorial from before around 2015 would have used `var`.

Comment: And for universal capability, many tutorials continue to use `var` because inertia. Any recent tutorial should at *least* be using `let`, preferably `const` when appropriate--but when the tutorial is about XYZ focusing on `var` vs. `let` vs. `const` often gets lost in the shuffle.

Comment: Do you encourage beginners to stick with `let`? I am finding `var` useful when I enter JS commands that redefine a variable that may or may not have already been created.

Comment: You *shouldn't* really have a definition of a variable that might or might not be defined already. That's defeating the purpose of defining a variable in the first place. With that you may as well be using globals. So, yes `let` is encouraged if at least to get you to structure your declarations properly. In real-world code `var` has pretty much no advantage outside some really odd cases where you can probably just re-structure your code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Var has a larger scope then let let is only valid in the block where it was declared .
Try adding 10 clickhandlers that output a numbers in a loop and you will quickly see the difference